# How to avoid using System GC in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, optimization, garbage-collection, bufferedreader

I have bolded what I thought should have resolved the issue. Basically, the bufferreader is not releasing the thread and its causing errors in the rest of my project.
`

```
public double fileGame(ArrayList<String> d) {
    System.out.println("file 1");
    String line;
    System.out.println(d.size());
    
    try {
        Month  Month = LocalDate.now().getMonth();
         String m = Month.toString().substring(0,3);
         System.out.println(m);
         int yr = LocalDate.now().getYear();
         String fin = m+" "+yr;
            Path gamepath = Paths.get(game);
            String dabe = "C:\\Users\OneDrive\\Documents\\financials\\tempread.csv";
            Path read = Paths.get(dabe);
            Files.copy(gamepath, read);
             Path New = Paths.get(dabe);
             Files.deleteIfExists(New);
            Files.copy(gamepath,New);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dabe));
            boolean cont = false; //checks if Game id is in paid list
            int i = 0;
            double paidAmount=0;
            while ((line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
                System.out.println(line+"li");
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                System.out.println(values.length+" size") ;
                String id = values[0];
                String date = values[1];
                String loc = values[2];
                Double amount = Double.parseDouble(values[3]);
                String by = values[4];
                String paid = values[5];
                Game g = new Game(id,date,loc,amount,by,paid);
                records.add(g);
                }
            while (i<records.size()&&d.size()>0) {
                System.out.println("Game Paid: "+records.get(i).getEverything());
                if(records.get(i).getId().equals(d.get(0))) {
                    records.get(i).setPaid();
                    paidAmount += records.get(i).getAmount();
                    records.get(i).setPaid();
                    records.get(i).setPaidMonth(fin);
                    System.out.println("Game Paid: "+records.get(i).getEverything());
                    d.remove(0);
                    if(records.size()==0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            **br.close();**
            Files.delete(read);
            System.out.println("br close");
        //  Files.deleteIfExists(gamepath);
            System.gc();
            fileGame2(records);
            return paidAmount;  
    }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

`

Deleting GC causes a "File is used by another process" at the next instance of me trying to replace the file.

Comment: There's nothing in bold, and have you considered using `Files#readAllLines()` instead? Also, OneDrive might be reading that file for upload while you're trying to delete it.

Comment: @nitind Sorry about that. br.close doesn't close the instance of the br reader which keeps the file that is called 'game' active. This is resolved addressed by System.gc, which isn't really good. The file game is used everywhere in the program, but i only really use the "flush" so I don't believe this is a widespread issue. Edit: Onedrive isn't active so its just a directory

Comment: Issue resolved. Had to move the fileGame2 method to outside the try catch. it created another instance of the same file. Curious on why   br.close does if it didn't prevent the issue

Comment: You should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Besides that, don’t mix NIO and old API. When you are already using `Path` and `Files`, why don’t you open the reader with [`Files.newBufferedReader(read)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path)). Though, your code looks like a perfect job for `Scanner`, so you can read the items (with the intended type, e.g. `double`) without creating line strings first, just to split them up.

Comment: By the way, it doesn’t matter, how often you call `Paths.get(…)` with the same string, the resulting objects will always represent the same path. So the sequence `Path read = Paths.get(dabe); Files.copy(gamepath, read); Path New = Paths.get(dabe); Files.deleteIfExists(New); Files.copy(gamepath,New);` copies a file to a location, just to delete the result afterwards and copy the file again to exactly the same location. But besides copying it twice, why are you copying it at all, when you can simply read it from the original location? Then, you don’t have to delete anything.